# Does PetaPoco's Query(string query, parameters) method protect from SQL injection?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-injection, petapoco

In [PetaPoco's home page](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) there is a mention that PetaPoco's SQL Builder (Sql object) protects from SQL injection. But does Query(string query, parameters) method protect from SQL injection?

SQL Builder is safe:

```
var id = 123;
var a = db.Query<article>(PetaPoco.Sql.Builder
  .Append("SELECT * FROM articles")
  .Append("WHERE article_id=@0", id)
);
```

But is it safe with string query where parameters are passed like this?

```
var id = 123;
var a = db.Query<article>("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id=@0", id);
```

Comment: Yes, if you try to start to look at PetaPoco's source code on github. It is after all using SqlParameter. https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/blob/development/PetaPoco/Database.cs#L952

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does protect against SQL injection.

You can verify this, if you aren't sure, by running a SQL Trace on the SQL being executed. Or provide some inputs with a single and a double quote in it (against a nvarchar column) and see whether a runtime exception occurs (which would occur if SQL injection was a problem).

See also https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/issues/326#issuecomment-238538854 :

> this is the correct behaviour. The SQL and parameters are passed to
>   the DB Command to prevent injection based attacks. The connected DB
>   will put the SQL and parameters together in a safe manner